# Cannot send mails using MS Graph in .NET Framework application

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I am maintaining an old **.NET Framework application (v4.7.2)**. It currently uses an in-house solution to send emails and read a mailbox on an Exchange Server, but this solution is being decommissioned and a**ll applications are supposed to move to Microsoft Graph**.

I have used MS Graph in other applications that are written in .NET Core, and it works in all of those. However, I cannot get it to work in this .NET Framework one. I have created a console application (in v4.8.1) to make it easy for me to test the code I have written, so that is what you'll see below. It uses **MS Graph 4.54.0**.

Note that the `Main` method of the `Program.cs` file consists solely of `new TestMailSender().Execute();`.

---

**Important UPDATE:**

The code below should be sufficient to construct your own console app. However, in order to make it easy, **I have [uploaded my code to Github](https://github.com/BJMdotNET/ms-graph-emails)**. Note that there are two versions in that repository:

- a .NET Framework 4.8.1 version with the same code as below, which **does not work**: the authentication succeeds, but the code throws an exception when trying to send emails.
- a .NET Core 6 version, which features virtually the same code, which **does work**.

Note that both versions use the same NuGet package when it comes to MS Graph.

To me it signals that the package **does not work correctly with .NET Framework**. If that is indeed the case, it is a major problem for me since upgrading the legacy project to .NET Core is not a feasible solution in the short term (since it would require a significant rewrite).

---

**TestMailSender**

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    public class TestMailSender : MailSender
    {
        public TestMailSender()
            : base()
        {
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            var subject = $"MS Graph Test {DateTime.Now.ToDdMmYyyyDashHhMm()}";

            var body = $"<html><body><h3>MS Graph Test {DateTime.Now.ToDdMmYyyyDashHhMm()}</h3></body></html>";

            Send(subject, body);
        }
    }
}
```

**MailSender**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    public abstract class MailSender
    {
        private readonly List<string> _destinationAddresses;

        protected MailSender()
        {
            _destinationAddresses = new List<string> { EmailSetting.Destination };
        }

        protected void Send(string subject, string body)
        {
            if (!_destinationAddresses.Any())
            {
                Trace.TraceError("No DestinationAddresses passed");
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                var mailMessage = SetupMailMessage(subject, body);

                new MsGraphMailService().SendMail(mailMessage).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                //Task.Run(() => new MsGraphMailService().SendMail(mailMessage)).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                var exceptionMessage = ExceptionMessageRetriever.Execute(exc);

                Trace.TraceError($"MailSender: Error while sending mail: {exceptionMessage}");
                Trace.TraceError($"MailSender: Error while sending mail: {exc}");

                throw;
            }
        }

        private MailMessage SetupMailMessage(string subject, string body)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"{GetType().Name} -> {MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()?.Name}");

            return new MailMessage
            {
                ToRecipients = _destinationAddresses,
                Subject = subject,
                Body = body,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**MsGraphMailService**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    internal class MsGraphMailService : MsGraphService
    {
        public async Task SendMail(MailMessage mailMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (GraphServiceClientToBeInitiated())
                {
                    await SetupGraphServiceClient().ConfigureAwait(false);
                }

                Trace.TraceInformation($"Sender: {EmailSetting.Sender}");

                var message = new Message
                {
                    ToRecipients = StringToGraphRecipient(mailMessage.ToRecipients),
                    CcRecipients = StringToGraphRecipient(mailMessage.CcRecipients),
                    BccRecipients = StringToGraphRecipient(mailMessage.BccRecipients),
                    Subject = mailMessage.Subject,
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Html,
                        Content = mailMessage.Body
                    },
                };

                await GraphServiceClient.Users[EmailSetting.Sender]
                    .SendMail(message, SaveToSentItems: true)
                    .Request()
                    .PostAsync()
                    //.ConfigureAwait(false)
                    ;
            }
            catch (ServiceException exc)
            {
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: {nameof(exc.StatusCode)} = [{exc.StatusCode}]");
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: {nameof(exc.Error)} = [{exc.Error}]");
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: {nameof(exc.Message)} = [{exc.Message}]");
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: {nameof(exc.RawResponseBody)} = [{exc.RawResponseBody}]");
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: {exc}");

                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                var exceptionMessage = ExceptionMessageRetriever.Execute(exc);

                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: Exception while sending mail: {exceptionMessage}");
                Trace.TraceError($"MsGraphMailService: Exception while sending mail: {exc}");

                throw;
            }
        }

        private List<Recipient> StringToGraphRecipient(List<string> recipients)
            => recipients?.Select(r => new Recipient { EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = r } }).ToList();
    }
}
```

**MsGraphService**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    internal abstract class MsGraphService
    {
        private static readonly string[] _scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

        protected GraphServiceClient GraphServiceClient;

        private DateTime? _validUntil;

        protected bool GraphServiceClientToBeInitiated()
        {
            return GraphServiceClient == null || !_validUntil.HasValue || DateTime.UtcNow > _validUntil;
        }
        
        protected async Task SetupGraphServiceClient()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"{GetType().Name} -> SetupGraphClient");

            var authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{MailConfiguration.MsGraph.TenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token";

            Trace.TraceInformation($"ClientId: {MailConfiguration.MsGraph.ClientId}");
            Trace.TraceInformation($"TenantId: {MailConfiguration.MsGraph.TenantId}");
            Trace.TraceInformation($"Authority: {authority}");

            var builder = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                .Create(MailConfiguration.MsGraph.ClientId);

            if (MailConfiguration.MsGraph.UseProxy)
            {
                builder.WithHttpClientFactory(new StaticClientWithProxyFactory());
            }

            builder.WithClientSecret(MailConfiguration.MsGraph.Secret)
                .WithAuthority(new Uri(authority))
                ;

            var app = builder.Build();

            var authenticationResult = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes).ExecuteAsync();

            Trace.TraceInformation($"Authentication result: {authenticationResult.AccessToken} expires on {authenticationResult.ExpiresOn}");

            // Create GraphClient and attach auth header to all request (acquired on previous step)
            _validUntil = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(59);
            
            GraphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(requestMessage =>
                {
                    requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));
        }
    }
}
```

**DateTimeExtensions**

```
using System;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    public static class DateTimeExtensions
    {
        public static string ToYyyyMmDdDashed(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }

        public static string ToDdMmYyyyDashHhMm(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return $"{dateTime.ToDdMmYyyyString()} - {dateTime.ToHhMmString()}";
        }

        public static string ToDdMmYyyyString(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        }

        public static string ToHhMmString(this DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpClientHandlerRetriever**

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security.Authentication;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    public static class HttpClientHandlerRetriever
    {
        public static HttpClientHandler Execute(bool useProxy = true, bool ignoreSslValidation = false)
        {
            var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            };

            if (useProxy)
            {
                httpClientHandler.UseProxy = true;
                httpClientHandler.Proxy = GetWebProxy();
                httpClientHandler.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }

            if (ignoreSslValidation)
            {
                httpClientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
                httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
            }

            return httpClientHandler;
        }

        private static WebProxy GetWebProxy()
        {
            return new WebProxy(Config.ProxyHost, Config.ProxyPort)
            {
                Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**MailMessage**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    internal class MailMessage
    {
        public List<string> ToRecipients { get; set; }

        public List<string> CcRecipients { get; set; }

        public List<string> BccRecipients { get; set; }

        public string Subject { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**StaticClientWithProxyFactory**

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    internal sealed class StaticClientWithProxyFactory : IMsalHttpClientFactory
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        static StaticClientWithProxyFactory()
        {
            var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandlerRetriever.Execute();

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new ProductInfoHeaderValue("MyCustomUserAgent", "1.0"));
        }

        public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            return _httpClient;
        }
    }
}
```

---

I have tested this with the proxy setting to "true" as well as "false". Note that this is running on a server in a corporate environment with a required proxy. Other applications using MS Graph run on that same server and operate without a problem.

The authentication succeeds, I have inspected the token that I get and it contains the correct information.

It is the call to send an email which fails. Unfortunately, the errors offer little explanation:

> MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: StatusCode = [0]
> MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: Error = [Code: generalException
> Message: An error occurred sending the request.
> ] 
> MsGraphMailService: ServiceException while sending mail: RawResponseBody = []

The only somewhat useful lines in the logs are these ones:

> ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: **Error 12007 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'The server name or address could not be resolved'.**
>
> [...]
>
> at MsGraphTester.MsGraphMailService.d__1.MoveNext() in MsGraphTester\MsGraphTester\MsGraphMailService.cs:line 46

Can anyone figure out where I'm going wrong?

(Does MS Graph even work in .NET Framework applications? And if so, does anyone have a working example?)

---

**Update:**

I have done a minor update to `HttpClientHandlerRetriever`:

```
httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;
```

I have also created a **StaticClientWithoutProxyFactory**:

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace MsGraphTester
{
    internal sealed class StaticClientWithoutProxyFactory : IMsalHttpClientFactory
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        static StaticClientWithoutProxyFactory()
        {
            var httpClientHandler = HttpClientHandlerRetriever.Execute(false, true);

            _httpClient = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
            _httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        }

        public HttpClient GetHttpClient()
        {
            return _httpClient;
        }
    }
}
```

Which I then use like this:

```
        if (MailConfiguration.MsGraph.UseProxy)
        {
            builder.WithHttpClientFactory(new StaticClientWithProxyFactory());
        }
        else
        {
            builder.WithHttpClientFactory(new StaticClientWithoutProxyFactory());
        }
```

But this does not solve the problem nor provide a different error.

Comment: The error is due to a timeout when the connection does not complete so you never get a response with a status code.  Most likely TLS is failing.  What encryption method is being used in the TLS certificate?  Older OS may not support the newer certificate.  TLS 1.3 will fail with a IIS server.

Comment: @jdweng Shouldn't the related code in the `HttpClientHandlerRetriever` handle the TLS failures? FYI I have updated my code to `httpClientHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12 | SslProtocols.Tls13;` and it continues to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I now have a working version, though it uses a kind of workaround. This was based on responses I got to [my bug report](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2080) on the Github of the MS Graph SDK.

I converted my code to use the latest version of the SDK, [v5.23.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph/5.23.0). (Note that there are significant changes between v4 and v5 of the package and that you need to change quite some code.)

I was asked to replace this part of the code:

```
await GraphServiceClient.Users[MailConfiguration.Email.Sender]
    .SendMail
    .PostAsync(sendMailPostRequestBody);
```

With this code, to "confirm if this issue is caused by the configuration of the client, or an environment issue":

```
var sendEmailRequestInformation = GraphServiceClient.Users[MailConfiguration.Email.Sender]
    .SendMail
    .ToPostRequestInformation(sendMailPostRequestBody);
var requestMessage = await GraphServiceClient.RequestAdapter.ConvertToNativeRequestAsync<HttpRequestMessage>(sendEmailRequestInformation);

var responseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(requestMessage);

if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    throw new Exception($"Failed to send email. Status code: {responseMessage.StatusCode}");
}
```

And this works!

For now this solves my issue. I hope that Microsoft will continue to investigate the issue and if possible offer an updated NuGet package.

Comment: I’m too, tried sending after changing an old console app but I was able to send quickly. My only problem now is file attachments. Not working. Getting null errors and can’t seem to have the message collection page that was there in the past. Any luck with that @BCdotWEB

Comment: @Y.G.J I don't need to send attachments, so I don't work on that. Try looking at the V5 migration guide? I used that when some months ago I had to migrate an app from MS Graph V4 to V5, but it was a frustrating effort since the guide wasn't correct IIRC.

Comment: I was able to send the email. Just needed to change the way i set attachment. Thanks